# expandable div issue with IE 6, 7, AND 8! What's the issue in my CSS?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html, expandable

For some reason, the following EXPANDABLE DIV won't work with IE 6,7 or 8. All it shows is static "CLICK HERE TO FIND A T-ZONE LOCATION IN YOUR NEIGHBOURHOOD" text that shows it's clickable, but won't expand or show the CSS styling. I'm assuming it's a compatibility issue with IE?

The code can be found here:
http://t-zonevibration.com/expandable_store_locator/

What's causing the conflict? Every other browser displays it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's because you are using an `<h9 />` element. I think they only go up to 6 and older IEs only recognise specific elements, ones it believes to be real. This is why there is an issue with the new HTML5 elements like `<header />`.

I'm pretty sure this will be the issue, try changing the element to a `<div />`

Comment: *My* browser goes all the way up to `<h11>`... you know, for those times when you need to give your headers that extra push over the cliff.

Comment: Okay, let me try that. It's being implemented into a Joomla template, so there's several h tags taken up and I didn't want to have any conflict (go figure). Stay tuned and thanks.

Comment: Okay, i changed the code. Took away the H9 element altogether and replaced it with a DIV. HOWEVER, I'm still seeing no styling and it doesn't appear to have been fixed.

Btw, is there somewhere I can browse a site using IE 6, etc.? Right now I've been viewing from Adobe Browser Lab.

Comment: I used to use an emulator called spoon. was fairly effective but difficult to remove again. BTW the site is working for me now...